# Eliminating empty values using arcade in ArcGIS Portal pop up?

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcade

I am attempting to create a conditional arcade expression that will list all of the fields that do not have a null value with an individual label and not show the field at all if the field is null. My current expression is below.

```
if (IsEmpty($feature.ABARTA_WI)){
return ""
} else {
return "Abarata: "+$feature.ABARTA_WI
}
```

This expression works in that it does not show the label or null value, but in the ArcGIS Portal pop up, it leaves an empty line for each one that is null, and I need it to not be there at all so the pop up is clean. As you can see below, this is creating empty lines in the popup.

[image: This is what the pop up currently looks like]

I would prefer the popup to display something like below, eliminating the empty lines.

```
Chief: 0.28
Chief WI MKR: 0.28
Enerplus: 0.3
```

Comment: When you return `""`, I believe that is not the same thing as `null`. That is an empty string, but still a string nonetheless, so it may be displaying that empty string in the line. Have you tried returning `null` or `None`, rather than `""`?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with ESRI and through testing we were able to determine that this is a bug. It gets repaired at 10.7, but amt software levels before 10.7 are not able ro stack labels using arcade.